# How to run code every 24h in android

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

In my application, I want run code every **24hours** for per user!
For example : When show `Toast` message on **12:00 am** , then show again this `Toast` message in **tomorrow 12:00**.

How can I do it?

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: There is a good tutorial here https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms and here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register an alarm, try below

**Step 1: Register an Alarm.**

```
private void registerAlarm(Context context, int requestCode) {
    int HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DailyAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
            + 24 * HOUR, pendingIntent);
}
```

Call registerAlarm method, for example from activity onCreate. **Ideally we should register at the time of app Install**

```
registerAlarm(this, 1);
```

**Step 2: Create BroadcastReceiver.**

```
public class DailyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Log.d("DailyAlarmReceiver","Received");
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Add receiver in manifest file**

```
<receiver
      android:name=".DailyAlarmReceiver"
      android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try and use `JobScheduler` class for this kind of use case its only supported beyond API level 21

https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129

Another alternative is to use `Firebase JobDispatcher`, but this comes with dependency of Google Play Services SDK.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling

Above link explains all other alternatives.

happy exploring ..!!